# Cannot answer letters C,D and E - ARRAY

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

Hi I need help I already got the **A** and **B** but for **C-E** I cannot get it

It needs to get the >=50 percent and print the Candidate name, I posted earlier about the sum suddenly, it also needs to get the highest number of votes and if there's no >=50 it needs to print the 2 largest and will print as run-off

[image]

Here is the code

```
//Prints table                  
    printf("Precint\t\tCandidate A\tCandidate B\tCandidate C\tCandidate D\n");
    for(rows=0; rows<5; rows++){
        printf("%d\t\t",k++);
        for(columns=0; columns<4; columns++){
            printf("%d\t\t",arr[rows][columns]);
        }   
        printf("\n");
    }
printf("\n\n");

//Computes Sum per Row
int Sum[4];
TSum=0;
for(rows = 0; rows < 4; rows++)
{     
    Sum[rows]=0;      
    for(columns = 0; columns < 5; columns++)
    {
        Sum[rows] += arr[columns][rows];
    }
    TSum += Sum[rows]; // only one operation per rows
}  

//Computes Percent and prints Table
double l1[4];
double l2[4];
double temp,i;

for(rows = 0; rows < 4; rows++)
{     
    Percnt[rows] = Sum[rows]/TSum*100;
    l++;
    printf("Candidate #%d Total:\t %d\t Percentage: %.0f%%\n",l, Sum[rows],Percnt[rows]);   

//finding largest   
  
        l1[rows] = Percnt[rows];
        l2[rows] = Percnt[rows];
        if (l1[rows] < l2[rows])
        {
            temp = l1[rows];
            l1[rows] = l2[rows];
            l2[rows] = temp;
        }

        for (i = 2; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (Percnt[rows] > l1[rows])
            {
                l2[rows] = l1[rows];
                l1[rows] = Percnt[rows];
            }
            else if (Percnt[rows] > l2[rows] && Percnt[rows] != l1[rows])
            {
                l2[rows] = Percnt[rows];
            }
        }  
//end
}

printf("\nSum: %.0f\n", TSum );
printf ("The FIRST LARGEST = %.0f\n", l1[rows]);
printf ("THE SECOND LARGEST = %.0f\n", l2[rows]);
```

[image]

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your question, pasting all text into the question with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

The part of the code where the `l1[rows]` and `l2[rows]` are assigned values seem wrong, they will have the same value each time. in the for loop that follows. you haven't made use of the variable `í`. Check the logic again